Issues related to mdc in css after upgrading angular material to 15
While upgrading angular material from 14 to 15, issues related to mdc have been introduced. Some of the material css were overriden in the previous version of angular and after upgrading due to mdc these overriden css no longer apply.
Please go through below scss:
.search-bar {
        background-color: #dadce0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 350px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        // border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;

        .mat-mdc-icon-button {
            transform: scale(1.4);

            &.search-icon:not([disabled]) {
                .mat-icon {
                    color: #fda57b;
                }
            }

            &.sidenav-collapse-icon {
                background-color: #fff;
                transform: scale(0.7);
                border-radius: 0px;
                padding-left: 10px !important;
                padding-top: 5px !important;

                .mat-icon {
                    color: #808080;
                }
            }
        }

        .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
            max-width: 40%;

            &.mat-form-field-disabled {

                /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
                .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
                    background-color: #e6e6e6;
                }
            }

            /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
            .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
                padding: 0px;
            }

            /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
            .mat-mdc-floating-label {
                margin-left: 5px;
            }

            /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
            /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
            /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
            .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
                background-color: #fff;

                /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
                /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
                .mat-mdc-form-text-infix {
                    border-top-width: 5px;

                    .mat-mdc-input-element {
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        padding-left: 5px;
                    }
                }

                /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
                .mat-mdc-form-field-text-suffix {
                    .mat-icon {
                        transform: scale(0.7);
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                }
            }

            /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of form-field that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
            .mdc-line-ripple {
                bottom: 0px;
            }
        }

        .st-pb-1 {
            padding-bottom: 3px;
        }
    }

none of the classes defined above are overridding the mdc classes. hence the changes are not reflecting.
I tried applying ::ng-deep but still the changes are not reflecting.
Is there any generic fix for these mdc issues?
